# Get first record based on time in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

DO we have a way to get first record considering the time.

> example
> `get first record today, get first record yesterday, get first record day before yesterday ...`

Note: I want to get all records considering the time

> sample expected output should be

```
first_record_today,
first_record_yesterday,..
```

Comment: provide sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question, the "first" record per day is the earliest one.

For that, we can use `RANK` and do the `PARTITION BY` the day only, truncating the time.

In the `ORDER BY` clause, we will sort by the time:

```
SELECT sub.yourdate FROM ( 
  SELECT yourdate, 
    RANK() OVER 
      (PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC('DAY',yourdate) 
       ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('SECOND',yourdate)) rk
    FROM yourtable
  ) AS sub 
  WHERE sub.rk = 1
  ORDER BY sub.yourdate DESC;
```

In the main query, we will sort the data beginning with the latest date, meaning today's one, if available.

We can try out here: [db<>fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/47d9b/14)

If this understanding of the question is incorrect, please let us know what to change by editing your question.

A note: Using a window function is not necessary according to your description. A shorter `GROUP BY` like shown in the other answer can produce the correct result, too and might be absolutely fine. I like the window function approach because this makes it easy to add further conditions or change conditions which might not be usable in a simple `GROUP BY`, therefore I chose this way.

**EDIT** because the question's author provided further information:

Here the query fetching also the first message:

```
SELECT sub.yourdate, sub.message FROM ( 
  SELECT yourdate, message,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC('DAY',yourdate) 
    ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('SECOND',yourdate)) rk
    FROM yourtable
  ) AS sub 
  WHERE sub.rk = 1
  ORDER BY sub.yourdate DESC;
```

Or if only the message without the date should be selected:

```
SELECT sub.message FROM ( 
  SELECT yourdate, message,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC('DAY',yourdate) 
    ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('SECOND',yourdate)) rk
    FROM yourtable
  ) AS sub 
  WHERE sub.rk = 1
  ORDER BY sub.yourdate DESC;
```

Updated fiddle here: [db<>fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5f16e/3)

Comment: thank you  very much for your answer .what i am expecting is get first **message**daily basis.

Comment: @rithuwa Please check my updated answer. Next time, it would be great to directly see this in your question. You didn't mention this ;)